# Calling auxiliar function from main function working in different routes [Node/express]

Tags: node.js, api, express, routes, controller

I have the following structure in the project:

```
root
├── models
├── routes
└── controllers
```

In the routes I specify the route-method pair. Something like this:

```
router.get('/',verifyToken,controller.getMethod)`
```

And in the controllers I have the different methods needed.

I have two methods in the same file (controller.js), let's call them aux and main. Method aux is executed in route '/A' and method main is executed in route '/B'.

The thing is that I'm trying to use the aux method inside the main. However, it won't be executed. I am working with morgan and I can see that the only method that is being executed is the main one.

I can't put them together because it is one auxiliar method out of many more that I need, so I need to keep them separated. I'm fairly new to js in general so any tip would be appreciated.

**My guess**

I think it has to be related to the routes because the main method is being executed as we're in the its route. However, when we try to call the aux method, it won't call the GET request, as we're not in its route.

However, I don't know how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand but lets try to unravel it now.

So if both your methods in different controllers, you can just call the aux file inside main using `import` or `require` and use the methods as you need. Just make sure you dont do it in both places as that results in a cyclic dependency error I think.

Maybe if you have some examples or snippets I can guide you better with this. But based on what I read I think you are having issue with calling methods from one file to other, which should be solved on basis of what I mentioned above.

Basically define the blocks of reusable methods/functions that you are using in your route file, OUTSIDE your route file somewhere. Then call that file and use the functions.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and your time. I know it's very confusing but I'll try my best to keep it as clear and as simple as possible. The problem is not the method importation (as they're in the same file). This would be the structure:

Comment: controller.methodA = async(req,res)=>{extracts data from the db}

Comment: controller.methodB = ()=>{this.methodA} //uses the info retrieved by methodA from the database

Comment: However, when I try to execute methodB, methodA is undefined/null... And I can see by the trace left by morgan, that the route that methodA needs to be in in order to extract the information is not there (in other words, as I'm on the route of methodB, I'm not in the route of methodA, thus it get's 404 and fails)

Comment: I'd love to go further, but I'm afraid StackOverflow would send the Minimal, reproducible...

Comment: No I think I understood what you mean. Maybe try putting this.methodA on await and wait for the response?
something like ` controller.methodB = async()=> { await this.methodA}

Comment: if you are getting 404 that means maybe you are not even reaching the endpoint. Try console to see if you are actually entering methodB first and then console inside the function block where you are using `this.methodA` to see if you are reaching there.

Comment: I've also tried the async but didn't do the trick. However, yes I'm aware that I don't reach the endpoint. As I got morgan, I can see the requests that are being made and this is the output:

Comment: GET /api/method-B, but never did the method A (they have different endpoints, and I know that's the issue) The thing is that I don't know if there is a way to redirect the method or something to the other route

Comment: Hmm okay. Try this, put a console log inside methodA and call methodB as you do. If you see the log at least you are reaching the method. Also I am not sure if you will see the methodA in morgan as you are actually calling methodB initially and that you are seeing, redirection inside it wont be spotted by morgan as per my knowledge (could be wrong).

Code wise you are actually not redirecting route but actually just using reusable code from another file inside your project so I am not sure if morgan would detect that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239036/discussion-between-felix-and-akshay-balwani).